# ASP.net c# Resize Image SQL Upload

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, image-uploading

I have been looking all over for a way to resize an image before it is uploaded to my database. Right now the files are just upload and if they are not the correct size then my pages look like a mess. How would I resize the image before I upload it to my database, I would like to upload an original sized image, and correct size. Is this possible with ASP.net. I have seen some tutorials on image resizing but none of them were helpful, if anyone can help that would be great. I started looking at [this](http://www.karpach.com/Server-side-thumbnail-generation.htm) tutorial but wasnt able to implement it in my SQL upload.

Thanks

Comment: could you share code of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Use the http://imageresizing.net library for the best image quality and for correct memory managememt. Using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()){ ImageBuilder.Current.Build(postedFile, ms, new ResizeSettings("maxwidth=800&maxheight=600&format=jpg"); return ms.ToArray();}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this, I am using MVC thus the `HttpPostedFileBase`. However this is taking the input of a `file` input type and returning a byte array, perfect for uploading to DB.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

private static byte[] PrepImageForUpload(HttpPostedFileBase FileData)
{
    using (Bitmap origImage = new Bitmap(FileData.InputStream))
    {
        int maxWidth = 165;

        int newWidth = origImage.Width;
        int newHeight = origImage.Height;          
        if (origImage.Width < newWidth) //Force to max width
        {
            newWidth = maxWidth;
            newHeight = origImage.Height * maxWidth / origImage.Width;   
        }

        using (Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight))
        {
            using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                gr.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                gr.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                gr.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                gr.DrawImage(origImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                newImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```